# Update <h:inputTextArea> content when string changed

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, richfaces

Ok, it's kind of a trivial question, but here it goes. I want to show the progress of various inserts/updates made on a database, using a `<h:inputTextArea value="bean.status" disabled="true"/>` in my view (using richfaces). The `Bean` is a backing bean with a `status` attribute and a method to add status messages it:

```
public void addMessage(String message) {
    status = status.concat(message + "\n");
}
```

There is a "migrate" button that starts the process. My problem is that the text area is update only at the end of the migrator method. What I need is that everytime the `status` is updated, the input text area gets updated too. So...

1 - How to do it?

2 - Is there a better way to implement this?

---

According to the RichFaces Component References it's needed:

- Setup Push
- Use a server-side or client-side approach
- Implement a message producer
- Handle push messages

So I did:

- Install runtime dependencies (Atmosphere):
  -- Added atmosphere-runtime-1.0.0.beta4 dependency with Maven
- Registering Push Servlet
  -- Not needed for Servlet 3.0, but added the manual configuration in web.xml:

  Push Servlet
      org.richfaces.webapp.PushServlet
      1
      true
- Chose server-side approach with Push CDI Event mechanism to fire messages. Updated my Status.java to be a message producer:

  import java.io.Serializable;
  import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
  import javax.enterprise.event.Event;
  import javax.inject.Inject;
  import javax.inject.Named;
  import org.richfaces.cdi.push.Push;

  @Named
  @SessionScoped
  public class Status implements Serializable {

  ```
  @Inject
  @Push(topic = "statusPush")
  Event<String> pushEvent;
  private String status;

  public void addMessage(String message) {
      //Everytime the status is updated...
      status = status.concat(message + "\n");
      //... the message is sent to the topic
      sendMessage(message);
  }

  public void sendMessage(String message) {
      pushEvent.fire(message);
  }


  public String getStatus() {
      return status;
  }

  public void setStatus(String status) {
      this.status = status;
  }
  ```

  }
- Handling messages on the view:

  ```
  <a4j:push address="statusPush"
      onerror="alert(event.rf.data)">
      <a4j:ajax event="dataavailable" render="statusOutput" />
  </a4j:push>


  <h:inputTextarea id="statusOutput" value="#{status.status}" cols="80" rows="20" disabled="true"/>
  ```

Seems that it's all set but when I click the button that starts the migration process, I get the following stacktrace:

> Warn: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406:
>   Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
>   com.google.common.collect.ComputationException:
>   javax.faces.FacesException: Lookup failed for '/ConnectionFactory' in
>   SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
>   java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
>   java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}   at
>   com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:397)
>     at
>   org.richfaces.application.push.impl.jms.JMSTopicsContextImpl.createTopic(JMSTopicsContextImpl.java:281)
>     at
>   org.richfaces.application.push.TopicsContext.getOrCreateTopic(TopicsContext.java:48)
>     at
>   org.richfaces.application.push.impl.SessionImpl.createSubscriptions(SessionImpl.java:190)
>     at
>   org.richfaces.application.push.impl.SessionImpl.subscribe(SessionImpl.java:185)
>     at org.richfaces.resource.PushResource.encode(PushResource.java:88)
>     at
>   org.richfaces.resource.UserResourceWrapperImpl.encode(UserResourceWrapperImpl.java:188)
>     at
>   org.richfaces.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:229)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:591)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.executeServlet(CometEngine.java:459)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.handle(CometEngine.java:316)   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometAsyncFilter.doFilter(CometAsyncFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.invokeFilters(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:171)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.interrupt(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:143)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.doTask(AsyncProcessorTask.java:102)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:193)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.execute(TaskBase.java:175)  at
>   com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncHandler.handle(DefaultAsyncHandler.java:145)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProtocolFilter.execute(AsyncProtocolFilter.java:210)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   javax.faces.FacesException: Lookup failed for '/ConnectionFactory' in
>   SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
>   java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
>   java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}   at
>   org.richfaces.application.push.impl.jms.JMSTopicsContextImpl$1.apply(JMSTopicsContextImpl.java:207)
>     at
>   org.richfaces.application.push.impl.jms.JMSTopicsContextImpl$1.apply(JMSTopicsContextImpl.java:195)
>     at
>   com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:355)
>     at
>   com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
>     at
>   com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
>     at
>   com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
>     at
>   com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:393)
>     ... 39 more Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed
>   for '/ConnectionFactory' in
>   SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
>   java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
>   java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root
>   exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ]    at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:654)
>     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:415)  at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:415)   at
>   org.richfaces.application.push.impl.jms.JMSTopicsContextImpl$JMSTopicContext.createConnection(JMSTopicsContextImpl.java:98)
>     at
>   org.richfaces.application.push.impl.jms.JMSTopicsContextImpl$JMSTopicContext.start(JMSTopicsContextImpl.java:123)
>     at
>   org.richfaces.application.push.impl.jms.JMSTopicsContextImpl$1.apply(JMSTopicsContextImpl.java:199)
>     ... 45 more Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:      at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.resolveContext(TransientContext.java:310)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:218)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:77)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:119)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:505)
>     ... 52 more

Bottom line: JMS (I think) can't find the `statusPush` topic.

update: had JMS enabled in web.xml, changed to

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.push.jms.enable</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and now stacktrace is:

> Warn: StandardWrapperValve[AutoRegisteredPushServlet]: PWC1406:
>   Servlet.service() for servlet AutoRegisteredPushServlet threw
>   exception java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.handler.ReflectorServletProcessor.onRequest(ReflectorServletProcessor.java:171)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:248)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:166)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.container.GrizzlyCometSupport.service(GrizzlyCometSupport.java:119)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.container.GlassFishWebSocketSupport.service(GlassFishWebSocketSupport.java:110)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:1257)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doPost(AtmosphereServlet.java:293)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doGet(AtmosphereServlet.java:279)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.executeServlet(CometEngine.java:459)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.handle(CometEngine.java:316)   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.comet.CometAsyncFilter.doFilter(CometAsyncFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.invokeFilters(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:171)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.interrupt(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:143)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.doTask(AsyncProcessorTask.java:102)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:193)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.execute(TaskBase.java:175)  at
>   com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncHandler.handle(DefaultAsyncHandler.java:145)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProtocolFilter.execute(AsyncProtocolFilter.java:210)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.richfaces.webapp.PushHandlerFilter.doFilter(PushHandlerFilter.java:90)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.util.AtmosphereFilterChain.doFilter(AtmosphereFilterChain.java:154)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.util.AtmosphereFilterChain.invokeFilterChain(AtmosphereFilterChain.java:131)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.handler.ReflectorServletProcessor$FilterChainServletWrapper.service(ReflectorServletProcessor.java:310)
>     at
>   org.atmosphere.handler.ReflectorServletProcessor.onRequest(ReflectorServletProcessor.java:168)
>     ... 40 more

Comment: Is change of status only triggered by UI?

Comment: no, only the classes that implement the migration process update the status attribute. Just to make it clearer: all the migration process is fired by one button. Then, when the methods responsible for the database operations perform a insert, the status on the UI must be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to periodically call the server and update your textarea. This can be achieved using a4j:poll component, that periodically fires ajax requests and updates specific fields on the form. An example could be found [here](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=poll).